# Accidentaly deteled python2.7 and roscore is dead

Tags: ros, python2.7, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I have accidentally deleted python2.7 and now I can't run roscore. I tried to reinstall it but..

```
roscore
^C... logging to /home/fish/.ros/log/b4e7951a-b47d-11e9-9717-9cb6d08c99cd/roslaunch-fish-XPS-13-9370-6045.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore", line 70, in <module>
    roslaunch.main(['roscore', '--core'] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 306, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunc

h/parent.py", line 226, in _start_infrastructure
    self._start_server()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 177, in _start_server
    self.server.start()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 376, in start
    code, msg, val = ServerProxy(self.uri).get_pid()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1283, in request


    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1311, in single_request
        self.send_content(h, request_body)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1459, in send_content
        connection.endheaders(request_body)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 836, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 566, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
        return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    KeyboardInterrupt
```

Please help! How can I repair it?

Ubuntu Xenial
ROS Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329818/accidentaly-deteled-python2.7-and-roscore-is-dead/) by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, those errors are more deeper than I thought...

I had experiences with this (most because of Open CV old version installed with Kinetic). My solution was to uninstall ROS, everything from python and then reinstall it.
I recommend to uninstall ROS following this:

```
sudo apt-get purge '^ros-*'
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then installing again (after python 2.7)

Try this and tell me later, best regards

---

Originally posted by [kaike_wesley_reis](https://answers.ros.org/users/40574/kaike_wesley_reis/) with karma: 61 on 2019-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) on 2019-08-02**:
It worked. I had some problems (" is not installed, so not removed") but I managed to solve them manually deleting the ROS folder from /etc. Thank you!

**Comment by [kaike_wesley_reis](https://answers.ros.org/users/40574/kaike_wesley_reis/) on 2019-08-02**:
Glad that I could helped!